# Can I remove LinkingTo dependencies after installation of an R package?

Tags: r, dplyr, package

Junior R developer here. I'm not really completely clear on the meaning of the LinkingTo field in an R package's dependencies.

What I would like to do is remove the package BH after the installation of dplyr. It's listed as a LinkingTo dependency of dplyr. The package takes up 154MB and my use case is very space sensitive. I've tried removing it and haven't seen any negative consequences (at least for the functions of dplyr that I'm using) but I'd like to understand the implications more thoroughly.

I know that Writing R Extensions says

> Specifying a package in ‘LinkingTo’ suffices if these are C++ headers containing source code or static linking is done at installation: the packages do not need to be (and usually should not be) listed in the ‘Depends’ or ‘Imports’ fields.

However, this seems to say multiple conflicting things to me. If it's static linking done at install, that suggests to me that LinkingTo package is really only needed while the dependent package is compiling and thereafter any necessary capabilities will be packaged into dependent shared library. The other statement "if these are C++ header containing source code" seems more ambiguous and suggests possible runtime dependencies. Meanwhile, "the packages do not need to be... listed in the ‘Depends’ or ‘Imports’ fields" suggests, given the meaning of Depends and Imports, that these dependencies are **not** needed at runtime.

So, are the LinkingTo dependencies needed at runtime or only at compile time? Once the dependent package is installed, can I simply remove them to save space?

In well over my head here and hoping someone can provide some advice.

Comment: I suspect the answer is that "it depends".  Do you know that `dplyr` uses static linking for whatever it gets from `BH`?

Comment: Hmm, I do not. And I'm not sure how to figure that out, either. Digging into what's going on behind the scenes in `dplyr` feels like it's probably a little beyond my abilities or at least a really impractical effort.